# Foreign key missing from migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the model trade/**Trade**.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from home.models import Player


class Trade(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buyer'),
    buyee = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buyee'),
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Model home/**Player**.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='user')
    value = models.IntegerField(default=1500)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner', blank=True, null=True)
```

A **Trade** happens between 2 **Player**s. That is, the *buyer* and *buyee* fields in **Trade** are foreign keys to **Player**.

Now, when I make migrations for the **Trade** model, this is what I get:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Trade',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('date', models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Why are the 2 foreign key fields missing from the migration?

Comment: have you register your **player model** app in settings.py

Comment: it should have created them I think reason it because django does not add migration until you use it somewhere (a simple import) try registering both models to admin and try running migrations again

Comment: @c.grey Trade and Player are in separate apps. They are both registered in settings.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Tried that. Still the same.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I'm afraid your suggestions are based on a serious misunderstanding. Migrations are "created" only when you ask for and "used" only when you ask for, and are in all cases _totally_ unrelated from the admin.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have experienced this. I created a Model but if I never used it in the code. Like imported no where just created it. Then `makemigrations` do not detect it. If you use it somewhere. It will. I understand we dont need to register the model to admin so I just wanted OP is using it somewhere please correct if I got something wrong

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew your migration should depend on the current "home" migration and include the foreign keys indeed. You may have a stall .pyc file somewhere or something wrong in your settings... NB: I assume you already created the migrations for the home app ?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari if your app is correctly registred, it's models ARE imported at startup, and makemigrations can not miss it. If you can constantly reproduce what you describe (creating a model in a _registered_ app and makemigration not detecting it) then you want to fill a bug report.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes. Migrations for the *home* app were done earlier. The **Trade** class is in *trade* app. I didn't understand how the migration should depend on *home* app. Did you mean the migration file would be created inside *home* instead of *trade*?

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew your `Trade` model has foreignkeys on `home.Player`, so the `trade_trade` table cannot be created before the `home_player` table. So your migration file should hold a reference (in the `.dependencies` list) to what was the latest `home` migration when you created the initial migration for `trade`. And of course NO the `trade` migrations won't go anywhere else than in "trade/migrations" ;-)

Comment: Documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#dependencies

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The `dependencies` list is empty in the migration file for `trade` app.

Comment: @NimishDavidMathew yes I saw this which is why I asked if "home" had been correctly registered and had it's migration applied _before_ you created the initial migration for "trade".   And at this point, since your initial trade migration is broken anyway and so hasn't been applied (you didn't apply it did you ???), the first thing I'd do would be to trash it (making sure there's no .pyc file left) and re-run makemigrations.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes. The `home` migrations were applied earlier. The `trade` migrations were applied too. Since it didn't create the foreign key columns, I applied the migrations again by deleting the migrations folder from `trade` app, removing the `trade` table and removing the migration entry for `trade` from migrations table. It still doesn't create the foreign key columns.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I didn't do the 'removing pyc files' part. Let me try that too.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I even created a new project and created the migrations from the beginning. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm totally clueless... You may want to search the Django project's bug tracker and eventually fill an issue with all relevant informations (IOW a full [mcve]).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Was a very silly mistake. I put commas at the end of fields.

Comment: Duh ! And I failed to catch them while they were obvious. Elephant in the room anyone ? :facepalm:

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers lol

Comment: yes you can... ok, me go grab some coffee -> []

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened due to the comma at the end of each field in the `Trade` class. Remove the commas and it will work.

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buyer')
    buyee = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buyee')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```